# Using shortcut keys in Gmail through QuickTest Pro

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts, qtp, browser-automation

When I'm in QTP and am automating a Gmail session a lot of the pages are dynamic. I need the line of code that will enable me to use keyboard shortcut keys within any of the gmail UI's.

Comment: have you tried anything specially sendkeys method?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to simulate keyboard action from QTP, [this article](http://www.learnqtp.com/ways-to-send-keyboard-input-to-an-application-using-qtp-when-it-does-not-record-using-normal-recording/) describes some of them. Especially check out `DeviceReplay`.

From the linked post:

```
Set obj = CreateObject("Mercury.DeviceReplay")
Window("Notepad").Activate
obj.PressKey 63
```

> **Note:** The PressKey method uses the appropriate ASCII or IBM Scan Code value for the key. "63" is the IBM Scan Code value for <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: Nice answer, most people would come up with a WshShell.Sendkeys solution while DeviceReplay is sometimes more usefull.